# Visual Studio 2010 - Double slash in Target name

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide, build

I just noticed my VS 2010 project uses two slashes between the full path and the executable name when linking the project (notice the \\ in the Debug\\TestQT.exe):

```
2>  LINK : ...\Project\TestQT\Proj\Win32\Debug\\TestQT.exe not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link
2>  Proj.vcxproj -> ...\Project\TestQT\Proj\Win32\Debug\TestQT.exe
2>FinalizeBuildStatus:
2>  Deleting file "Debug\TestQT.unsuccessfulbuild".
2>  Touching "Debug\TestQT.lastbuildstate".
2>
2>Build succeeded.
```

Should I be worried? The reason I ask the question is that occasionally, my VS 2010 keeps suggesting me to rebuild the project before debugging even though everything is rebuilt before I hit F5. I suspect this has something to do with the double-slash vs single slash paths during dependencies check. Though, restarting the IDE **sometimes** helps, so I am not sure this is related to the double slash.

Thanks

 Alex